# Create a batch file to list all files in each folder in separate text files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

For example 
I have 3 folders named A,B,c
each of them contain 100s of PDFs and Excel files.
I need a batch file to list all these files in a text document separately

I tried this but the result was not what I expected:

```
ECHO OFF
dir /s /a-d > list.txt
```

Comment: ECHO OFF

dir /s /a-d > list.txt

Comment: each folder should have a separate file

Comment: I updated your question with what you tried.

Comment: What do you mean by seperately? Do you want to seperately list all the pdf's in one file, xls in another? or do you want to list all files seperately in `a` and a diffrent list for `b` and `c` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a potential solution for the task, based upon what I understood your question to be requesting.

*Please note however, that this site is not a request service, your provided code is supposed to have attempted the task you've laid out, not do something different and ask someone to write one which does!*

From the **Command Prompt**:

```bat
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %A In ('Dir/B/AD 2^>Nul')Do @PushD "%A"&Dir/B/A-D>"list.txt"&PopD
```

From a **Batch File**:

```bat
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Dir/B/AD 2^>Nul')Do @PushD "%%A"&Dir/B/A-D>"list.txt"&PopD
```

---

If you don't want the list.txt to list itself…

From the **Command Prompt**:

```bat
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %A In ('Dir/B/AD 2^>Nul')Do @PushD "%A"&Dir/B/A-D 2>Nul|Find /V "list.txt">"list.txt"&PopD
```

From a **Batch File**:

```bat
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('Dir/B/AD 2^>Nul')Do @PushD "%%A"&Dir/B/A-D 2>Nul|Find /V "list.txt">"list.txt"&PopD
```

---

***Notes:***

- The examples above use the `Dir` command in such a way as to see everything, please be aware that in some instances, for obvious reasons, you may be better advised to include one or more of `-H`, `-L`, `-R` & `-S` with the `/A` option too, e.g. `Dir/B/AD-L`, or `Dir/B/A-D-H`.
- I have completely ignored the fact that there may already be a `list.txt` file in any one of those directories, meaning that if there is, it would be overwritten. For this reason you should choose a less common name or extension for the output file.